# I am building customize openssl 1.0.2f for RHEL 5 from Fedora source rpm but it gives me error

Tags: linux, openssl

Source rpm used:- openssl-1.0.2f-1.fc23.src.rpm

For RHEL 6 , I can build openssl1.0.2f without any issues

But for RHEL 5, When I am running:-

rpmbuild -bb openssl.spec

Initially it ask for lksctp dependency which I have installed

lksctp-tools-1.0.6-3.el5.x86_64.rpm
lksctp-tools-devel-1.0.6-3.el5.x86_64.rpm

It gives me below error:-

```
_ENDIAN -Wall -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -Wa,--noexecstack -DPURIFY -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM   -c -o bss_dgram.o bss_dgram.c
bss_dgram.c: In function 'BIO_new_dgram_sctp':
bss_dgram.c:973: error: storage size of 'auth' isn't known
bss_dgram.c:992: error: 'SCTP_AUTH_CHUNK' undeclared (first use in this function)
bss_dgram.c:992: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
bss_dgram.c:992: error: for each function it appears in.)
bss_dgram.c:993: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct sctp_authchunk'
bss_dgram.c:1001: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct sctp_authchunk'
bss_dgram.c:1020: error: 'SCTP_LOCAL_AUTH_CHUNKS' undeclared (first use in this function)
bss_dgram.c:1029: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
bss_dgram.c:1081: error: 'SCTP_PARTIAL_DELIVERY_POINT' undeclared (first use in this function)
bss_dgram.c:973: warning: unused variable 'auth'
bss_dgram.c: In function 'dgram_sctp_read':
bss_dgram.c:1225: error: 'SCTP_SENDER_DRY_EVENT' undeclared (first use in this function)
bss_dgram.c:1266: error: 'struct sctp_event_subscribe' has no member named 'sctp_sender_dry_event'
bss_dgram.c:1317: error: 'SCTP_PARTIAL_DELIVERY_POINT' undeclared (first use in this function)
bss_dgram.c:1358: error: 'SCTP_PEER_AUTH_CHUNKS' undeclared (first use in this function)
bss_dgram.c:1362: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
bss_dgram.c: In function 'dgram_sctp_ctrl':
bss_dgram.c:1504: error: storage size of 'authkeyid' isn't known
bss_dgram.c:1558: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct sctp_authkeyid'
bss_dgram.c:1560: error: 'SCTP_AUTH_ACTIVE_KEY' undeclared (first use in this function)
bss_dgram.c:1566: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct sctp_authkey'
bss_dgram.c:1573: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
bss_dgram.c:1579: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
bss_dgram.c:1581: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
bss_dgram.c:1581: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
bss_dgram.c:1581: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
bss_dgram.c:1581: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
bss_dgram.c:1584: error: 'SCTP_AUTH_KEY' undeclared (first use in this function)
bss_dgram.c:1593: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct sctp_authkeyid'
bss_dgram.c:1602: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct sctp_authkeyid'
bss_dgram.c:1612: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct sctp_authkeyid'
bss_dgram.c:1637: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct sctp_authkeyid'
bss_dgram.c:1659: error: 'SCTP_AUTH_DELETE_KEY' undeclared (first use in this function)
bss_dgram.c:1660: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'struct sctp_authkeyid'
bss_dgram.c:1504: warning: unused variable 'authkeyid'
bss_dgram.c: In function 'BIO_dgram_sctp_wait_for_dry':
bss_dgram.c:1782: error: 'struct sctp_event_subscribe' has no member named 'sctp_sender_dry_event'
bss_dgram.c:1834: error: 'SCTP_SENDER_DRY_EVENT' undeclared (first use in this function)
bss_dgram.c:1854: error: 'struct sctp_event_subscribe' has no member named 'sctp_sender_dry_event'
make[2]: *** [bss_dgram.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/openssl_102f_parashar/BUILD/openssl-1.0.2f/crypto/bio'
make[1]: *** [subdirs] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/openssl_102f_parashar/BUILD/openssl-1.0.2f/crypto'
make: *** [build_crypto] Error 1
error: Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.44794 (%build)


RPM build errors:
    Bad exit status from /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.44794 (%build)
```

Is this issue with code?
Any pointer on this area will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You almost answered it for yourself, I had the same problem and upgrading lksctp-tools (I used 1.0.16) solved the build issue.